# Given x,y,z coord, how do you find out if a node exists there and if so, which one?

Tags: scenekit

I have a .dae file with 2 spheres named "ball1" and "ball2".

- ball1 at x:0 y:0 z:0
- ball2 at x:1 y:0 z:0

At one point in the code, an x,y,z coord is given.  The given coord may be the same as one of the balls but not necessarily.  How do you check what node exists at given coord if one exists there at all?

```
 let sceneBall1 = scnView.scene!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("ball1", recursively: true)
 let sceneBall2 = scnView.scene!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("ball2", recursively: true)

 var posball1:SCNVector3 = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
 var posball2:SCNVector3 = SCNVector3(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0)
```

If I want to know what node I tap on I can just do this:

```
 if result.node!.name!.hasPrefix("ball1") {
      println("You tapped ball1.")
 } else {
      println("You tapped ball2.")
```

But I'm not given a tapped result node, just the x,y,z.

Comment: do you want to know if a given point is inside the geometry? Or if this point is the location of a node? The latter is easy, loop over your nodes and check against their `position`

Comment: The given x,y,z will be the node position or it won't, so the latter. Can you expand on looping over my nodes please and thanks!

Comment: well, you test if `(x,y,z)` equals `ball1.position`. If it does, your result is `ball1`. Otherwise you test if `(x,y,z)` equals `ball2.position`.  If it does, your result is `ball2`. Otherwise your result is `nil`

Comment: OK. You answered it manages. But what if I don't know ball1.position because it moves around. Hey ball1, what's your current position?

Comment: if the node has implicit or explicit animations, or has a physics body, you can get its position through `node.presentationNode.position`. Otherwise `node.position` will do.

Comment: You're awesome, mnuages!

Answer (score 0):

*mnuages* showed me the way.  It comes down to this:

```
 if ball1!.position.x == givenX && ball1!.position.y == givenY {
            println("ball1 is here.")
        }
```

Comment: you can also have a look at `SCNVector3EqualToVector3`

Comment: Hey. I will. Thanks a ton for your help today.  It helped so much.  You should write an answer to this question--just paste what you originally posted and I'll accept your answer and get rid of mine. Again, thank you, mnuages!

Answer (score 0):

@objc func tappedNode(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

```
    let location = sender.location(in: sceneView)

    // When tapped on the object, call the object's method to react on it
    let sceneHitTestResult = sceneView.hitTest(location, options: nil)
    if !sceneHitTestResult.isEmpty {
        // We only have one content, so we know which node was hit.
        // If the scene contains multiple objects, you would need to check here if the right node was hit
        let lastNode = sceneHitTestResult.last?.node

        print(lastNode?.name)
    }

}
```